# Facing error while Read Data from Pubsub using Beam

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I am new to Beam and am trying to get my hands dirty. I am reading from a JSON file and sending the data to the pub-sub topic. Below is the code snippet. My intention is to read the data from pub-sub and send it to BigQuery.

**publishEvents.py**

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from concurrent import futures
from typing import Callable

project='ApacheBeam'
topic='incomingData'
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path( project, topic)
publish_futures = []

def get_callback(
    publish_future: pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future, data: str
) -> Callable[[pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future], None]:
    def callback(publish_future: pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future) -> None:
        try:
            # Wait 60 seconds for the publish call to succeed.
            print(publish_future.result(timeout=60))
        except futures.TimeoutError:
            print(f"Publishing {data} timed out.")

    return callback

for line in open('/home/test/Resources/Input/Input_Data.json', 'r'):
    traffic=json.loads(line)
    data=str(traffic)
    #publisher.publish(topic_path, str.encode(str(key),"utf-8"))
    publish_future=publisher.publish(topic_path,data.encode("utf-8"))
    publish_future.add_done_callback(get_callback(publish_future, data))
    publish_futures.append(publish_future)
futures.wait(publish_futures, return_when=futures.ALL_COMPLETED)

print(f"Published messages with error handler to {topic_path}.")
```

**Input_Data.json**

```
{
    "user_id": "102105290400257936",
    "event_ts": "2021-05-29 00:03:12.262 UTC",
    "event_id": "Change_User_Name",
    "country": "US",
    "game": "gru",
    "user_group": "[1, 529701]",
    "user_condition": "[1]",
    "device_type": "tablet",
    "device_model": "iPhone13,2",
    "user_name": "Gin47709426",
    "fb_connect": false,
    "event_payload": "{\"trigger\":\"install\"}",
    "is_active_event": true
}
```

**readFromPubSub.py**

```
import argparse
import ast
import json
import os
import logging
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Service account key path
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "home/test/Resources/Config/gcpkey.json"
INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION = "projects/ApacheBeam/subscriptions/ReadData"
BIGQUERY_TABLE = "ApacheBeam:JSONData.StoreEvents"
BIGQUERY_SCHEMA = "user_id:STRING,event_ts:STRING,create_ts:STRING,event_id:STRING,ifa:STRING,  ifv:STRING, country:STRING,chip_balance:STRING,game:STRING,user_group:STRING,user_condition:STRING,device_type:STRING,device_model:STRING,user_name:STRING,fb_connect:BOOLEAN,is_active_event:BOOLEAN,event_payload:STRING" 


class CustomParsing(beam.DoFn):
    """ Custom ParallelDo class to apply a custom transformation """

    def to_runner_api_parameter(self, unused_context):
        # Not very relevant, returns a URN (uniform resource name) and the payload
        return "beam:transforms:custom_parsing:custom_v0", None

    def process(self, element: bytes, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
        """
        Simple processing function to parse the data and add a timestamp
        For additional params see:
        https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.7.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn
        """
        parsed = json.loads(element.decode("utf-8"))
        json_data = ast.literal_eval(parsed)
        t=json.dumps(json_data)
        t["timestamp"] = timestamp.to_rfc3339()
        yield t

        


def run():
    # Parsing arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--input_subscription",
        help='Input PubSub subscription of the form "projects/<PROJECT>/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION>."',
        default=INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--output_table", help="Output BigQuery Table", default=BIGQUERY_TABLE
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--output_schema",
        help="Output BigQuery Schema in text format",
        default=BIGQUERY_SCHEMA,
    )
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    # Creating pipeline options
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

    # Defining our pipeline and its steps
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        (
            p
            | "ReadFromPubSub" >> beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(
                subscription=known_args.input_subscription, timestamp_attribute=None
            )
            | "CustomParse" >> beam.ParDo(CustomParsing())
            | "WriteToBigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                known_args.output_table,
                schema=known_args.output_schema,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            )
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

I have updated the code and now I am getting errors while reading the data from pub-sub(though I have added ast eval. But I am unable to resolve it. Can anybody help?

**Error snippet**

```
RuntimeError: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1) [while running 'CustomParse']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below example code of pipeline to read data from Pub/Sub and write to BigQuery using Apache Beam.

```
import argparse
import json
import os
import logging
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Service account key path
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "credentials/e62e3e6ed7d7.json"
INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION = "projects/PROJECT_ID/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_NAME"
BIGQUERY_TABLE = "PROJECT_ID:DATASET_NAME.TABLE_NAME"
BIGQUERY_SCHEMA = "timestamp:TIMESTAMP,attr1:FLOAT,msg:STRING"


class CustomParsing(beam.DoFn):
    """ Custom ParallelDo class to apply a custom transformation """

    def to_runner_api_parameter(self, unused_context):
        # Not very relevant, returns a URN (uniform resource name) and the payload
        return "beam:transforms:custom_parsing:custom_v0", None

    def process(self, element: bytes, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
        """
        Simple processing function to parse the data and add a timestamp
        For additional params see:
        https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.7.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn
        """
        parsed = json.loads(element.decode("utf-8"))
        parsed["timestamp"] = timestamp.to_rfc3339()
        yield parsed


def run():
    # Parsing arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--input_subscription",
        help='Input PubSub subscription of the form "projects/<PROJECT>/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION>."',
        default=INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--output_table", help="Output BigQuery Table", default=BIGQUERY_TABLE
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--output_schema",
        help="Output BigQuery Schema in text format",
        default=BIGQUERY_SCHEMA,
    )
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    # Creating pipeline options
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

    # Defining our pipeline and its steps
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        (
            p
            | "ReadFromPubSub" >> beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(
                subscription=known_args.input_subscription, timestamp_attribute=None
            )
            | "CustomParse" >> beam.ParDo(CustomParsing())
            | "WriteToBigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                known_args.output_table,
                schema=known_args.output_schema,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            )
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

To publish messages on Pub/Sub, deploy the pipeline and for more information you can refer to this [documentation](https://medium.com/codex/a-dataflow-journey-from-pubsub-to-bigquery-68eb3270c93).

Comment: I have modified the code.I am getting a different error now related to JSON

Comment: The input json file and BigQuery schema that you have given inside the code seems different. For more information you can refer to this [document](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.14.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html).